# jquery validation not working for forms in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Thanks in advance,I am new to cakephp.I am using cakephp 2.8.5 version. Actually I have downloaded jquery.validate.min.js file to validate my add user form which is add.ctp file. In this file I have used

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min'); ?>
```

to include the library file. In `add.ctp` file the jquery validation code is not working even i got a reference from google that i have to use double quotes for username textbox field like this `"data[User][username]"` instead of `data[User][username]`. But in my form I have to use `data[User][username]` for the username field. I have written a validation code but I am not getting any error. please anyone help me how to do this. For checking purpose I have written validation code for only up to phone textbox field.

My `adduser.ctp` file as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>              

        <?php echo $this->Html->css('sb-admin-2'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->css('sb-admin-2.min'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('sb-admin-2'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('sb-admin-2.min'); ?>

        <?php echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui.min');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min');?>     
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui.min');?>    

        <?php echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min'); ?>      

        <style type="text/css">   

        </style> 
        <script>
          $(function() {

        // Setup form validation on the #register-form element 
        $("#UserAddForm").validate({ 

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                "data[User][username]": "required",
                "data[User][password]": {
                    required: true
                    minlength: 5
                },            
                "data[User][full_name]": "required",
                "data[User][email]": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                "data[User][phone]": "required",  
                //'role': "required"             

            },

            // Specify the validation error messages 
            messages: {
                "data[User][username]": "Please enter the Username",
                "data[User][full_name]": "Please enter your Full Name",  
                "data[User][password]": {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be atleast 5 characters long"
                }, 
                "data[User][email]": "Please enter a valid email address"  

            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }       


        });

      });  

        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

      <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h3 class="page-header">Add User</h3> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 --> 
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                               <!-- Form Name -->
                               Enter User Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <form role="form" name="add_userform" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="UserAddForm" action="/invl_exams/users/add"> 
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Username</label>  
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserUsername" maxlength="255" name="data[User][username]">   
                                                <!--<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p> --> 
                                                <label id="UserUsername-error" class="error" for="UserUsername"></label> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                                <label>Password:</label>                                    
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPassword" name="data[User][password]">
                                                <label id="UserPassword-error" class="error" for="UserPassword"></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Full Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserFullName" maxlength="255" name="data[User][full_name]">
                                                <label id="UserFullName-error" class="error" for="UserFullName"></label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Email</label>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][email]">
                                                <label id="UserEmail-error" class="error" for="UserEmail"></label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Secondary Email</label>                             
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][secondary_email]">
                                                <label id="UserSecEmail-error" class="error" for="UserSecEmail"></label>
                                            </div>

                                             <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Phone</label>                             
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][phone]">
                                                <label id="UserPhone-error" class="error" for="UserPhone"></label>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Secondary Phone</label>  
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][secondary_phone]">
                                                <label id="UserSecPhone-error" class="error" for="UserSecPhone"></label>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Location</label>  
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecLoc" maxlength="255" name="data[User][location]">
                                                <label id="UserLocation-error" class="error" for="UserLocation"></label>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label>Business Name</label>  
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserBusinessName" maxlength="255" name="data[User][business_name]">
                                                  <label id="UserBusiness-error" class="error" for="UserBusinessName"></label>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                               <label for="UserDocument">Document</label>     
                                                <select class="form-control" required="required" id="UserDoc" name="data[User][document]">
                                                 <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                                  <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
                                                  <option value="License Certificate">License Certificate</option> 
                                                  <option value="Aggrement Copy">Aggrement Copy</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <label id="ExamName-error" class="error" for="UserDocument"> </label>
                                              </div>
                                              <!--<div class="form-group">
                                                <label>File input</label>
                                                <input type="file">
                                              </div> -->

                                              <div class="form-group" id="ShowDoc" style="display:none">
                                                <label>File</label> 
                                                <!--<input name="data[Document][docfile]" id="DocumentSubmittedfile" type="file"> -->
                                                <!--<input type="file" name="data[User][docfile]" id="usersFile"/>-->
                                                <?php //echo $this->Form->input('doc_file',array( 'type' => 'file','error' => false,'placeholder'=>'Upload Image')); ?> 
                                                <?php echo $this->Form->file('Document.submittedfile');  ?> 
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                 <h4 class="page-header">Point of Contact</h4> 
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label>Name</label>    
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pname" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pname]">
                                                  <label id="UserPName-error" class="error" for="UserPName"></label>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label>Email</label>                                      
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pemail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pemail]">
                                                  <label id="UserPEmail-error" class="error" for="UserPEmail"></label>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label>Phone</label>  
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pOfc_phone]">
                                                  <label id="UserpPhone-error" class="error" for="UserPEmail"></label>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group"> 
                                                  <label>Designation</label>  
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="pDesign" maxlength="255" name="data[User][pdesignation]"> 
                                                  <label id="UserpPhone-error" class="error" for="UserpDesign"></label>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">NEXT</button> 
                                              </div>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->

                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.panel-body -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
               <!-- /.Page wrapper -->
          </div>
              <!-- /.Wrapper -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma in

```
"data[User][password]": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/k8z2xqfh/

Comment: I used your code in seperate test file it's working fine but in my cakephp page its not working. Is there any problem in including jquery library file?

Comment: do you know what a console is and how to use it?

Comment: Ya i am using fire bug . In the console it's showing this error : TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Comment: Is this is the way to include jquery library file in cakephp2.8.5 version

Comment: Like this <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min'); ?>

Comment: I have included jquery library file as per documentation like this <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min.js'); ?>     
   but it's not working

Comment: I am getting the same error in the console like this jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).validate is not a function

@http://localhost/invl_exams/add:186:6
g/</j@http://localhost/invl_exams/js/jquery.js:2:29566
g/</k<@http://localhost/invl_exams/js/jquery.js:2:29882

undefined
jquery.js (line 2)
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
 

$("#UserAddForm").validate({

Comment: There was a conflit between the validate function in jquery so i used var j = jQuery.noConflict(); Everywhere instead of " $ " i uesd " j " to avoid the conflit , now it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you very much madalin ivascu